# How to verify Time configuration in 2012R2 Domain enviroment

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to verify the time configuration in a domain environment and need some guidance. I have identified the domain controller which has the PDC emulator role and it's a 2012R2 hyper-v machine. This machine does have "time synchronization" enabled under integration services. I have run the time query status and see "Source: VM IC Time Synchronization Provider (Virtual)".   I read through Ben Armstrong's blog but it's still not clear if this source is correct or not? Shouldn't this be pointing to an external ntp source?
Thanks!

Comment: `Shouldn't this be pointing to an external ntp source?` - Yes it should. - http://jackstromberg.com/2013/10/configuring-external-time-source-on-your-primary-domain-controller/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your PDC should be polling an external NTP source. You can change the settings via an admin cmd prompt.

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org"
w32tm /config /reliable:yes
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update
```

And to verify the changes:
`w32tm /query /configuration`

Comment: Thanks, in my case my pdc emulator domain controller is a virtual machine, i'm reading there may be a registry tweak as well, anyone have any details about this?

Comment: You really shouldn't have to tweak anything else in the registry. Also, if your virtual host is already using NTP, using the integration service time sync is pretty much the same thing as directly syncing.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you my experience and my setup.  I use an "external" NTP server for my forest -- it is the external DNS server where I am.  I don't manage it, but I believe it syncs up to an internet time source.  My forest root PDC role holder is a physical box.  All my PDC role holders in my domains are physical boxes as well.  All of my Hyper-V physical hosts have a time sync agent on them that connect to the physical forest root PDC role holder and update time every minute.

I have read all of the internet wisdom of 'this is worked out and it will all be fine you don't need to worry about a virtual DC having time drift issues.'  That has NOT been my experience!  Time sync issues are the main reason that I fight with the bean counters about having at least one physical DC in my domains.  In my experience we have had time drift issues at least once a year when we have left the domains to just sync time on their own because of virtual DCs.

What happens when the physical Hyper-V host has a virtual DC on it and that host asks the DC on it what time it is?  It gets into a loop that allows for time drift.  The host forces the DC to a particular time and the DC tells the host to be the time is was just forced to be by the host.  The time the virtual DC got from the domain PDC was lost because of the time sync from the host just squashed it and time begins to drift.  Over the course of the year it can get out by 5 minutes.  I have not had this issue in a couple years since I have installed the time sync agent on all my Hyper-V boxes.

This [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertvi/2011/05/11/time-synchronization-and-domain-controller-vms/) gives three different answers.  My answer works for me in my environment and I hope my answer helps you or makes sense as to why I do it my way.